# Magento 2 Pass array data to Custom Email template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email-templates, magento2.4, array

I'm a beginner in magento and I have a custom email template as follows

wishlist_email_template.html

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
            <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{var heading}}</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var feedback}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{layout handle="wishlist_email_products" products=$products area="frontend"}}

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA;text-align:center;">
                        <center>
                            <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">
                                <strong> Thank you</strong>
                            </p>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

SendWishlistEmail.php

```
   foreach ($toEmail as $receiver) {
            $receiverMail = $receiver;
            try {
                // template variables pass here
                $templateVars = [
                    'heading' => 'Wishlist',
                    'msg' => 'test',
                    'msg1' => 'test1',
                    'products'=> $products,
                    'images'=> $images,
                    'feedback' =>$feedback
                ];

                $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

                $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
                $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

                $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
                $templateOptions = [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $storeId
                ];
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->addTo($receiverMail)
                    ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_logger->info($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

$products is my array,
I'm trying to get my product data from product array using {{layout handle="wishlist_email_products" products=$products area="frontend"}}.

wishlist_email_products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="email/product.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

product.html

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 */
$products = $block->getProducts();
?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $product->getSku() ?></td>
        <td><?= $product->getName() ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I get the error Error

```
filtering template: Invalid template file: 'app/code/NeoSolax/Custom/view/frontend/templates/email/product.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'additional.product.info'
```

in my sent email
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the xml will fix:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">
<body>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="NeoSolax_Custom::email/product.phtml"/>
</body>
```